# Laravel Auth::attempt worked but now failed

Tags: php, laravel, login-attempts

Today I want to show my website to my friend. I did `git pull`, `artisan migrate`, `seed`, `key generate` and generated the `.env` file correctly. But when we want to login, it's doesn't works.

The login is working for me. Logout / Login. Nevermind, it's worked!! I copy the project to the new folder and make a fresh install from Git repo (maybe some file not added). It's not working. Okay, I'm happy because I think I forgot to add a file to Git. I copy back my original files to original path and try to login. Not working. Anyone have any idea for this?

### Controller

```
if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
    'email_address' => $request->get('email_address'),
    'login_passwd' => $request->get('login_passwd'),
    'status_active' => true,
    'status_admin' => 1,])) {
         return redirect( route('backend::dashboard.core') );
}
```

### Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class UsersCore extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;

    protected $table = 'users_core';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $incrementing = true;

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function usersData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UsersData', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->attributes['login_passwd'];
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using ubuntu or linux ? when try to new environment?

Comment: No.. I working in windows, but now working! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. My password column named as `login_passwd` but the `auth::guard->attempt` validates on a column named `password`, so I renamed my column to `password` and it's working!

Comment: Don't forget to [accept your own answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)!